# Machine Learning Classification of Lists of Strings in JAVA without any context surrounding them

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, text-classification, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction

I have several lists of Strings already classified like

```
<string>                        <tag>    

088 9102355                     PHONE NUMBER
091 910255                      PHONE NUMBER
...
Alfred St                       STREET
German St                       STREET
...
RE98754TO                       IDENTIFIER
AUX9654TO                       IDENTIFIER
...
service open all day long       DESCRIPTION
service open from 8 to 22       DESCRIPTION
...
jhon.smith@email.com            EMAIL
jhon.smith@anothermail.com      EMAIL
...
www.serviceSite.com             URL
...
Florence                        CITY
...
```

with a lot of strings per tag and i have to make a java program which, given
a new List of String(supposed all of the same tag), assigns a probability for each tag to the list.
The program has to be completely language independent and all the knowledge has to came from the lists of tagged strings as the one described above.

I think that this problem can be solved with NER approaches (i.e machine learning algorithms like CRF) but those are usually for unstructured text like a chapter from a book, or a paragraph of a web page, and not for list of independent strings.

I Thought to use CRF (i.e Conditional Random Field) because I found a similar approach used in the Karma Data integration Tool as described in this [Article](http://www.isi.edu/integration/papers/knoblock12-eswc.pdf), paragraph 3.1
where the "semantic  types" are the my tags.

To tackle the program I have downloaded the [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) and played a bit
with it's JAVA API through NERDemo.java finding two problems:

1. the training file for the CRFClassifier has to have one word per row, therefore I haven't found a way to classify groups of words with a single tag
2. I don't understand if I have to make one Classifier per tag or a single        Classifier for all, because a single string could be classified with n different tags and it is the user that chooses between them. So I'm rather interested in the probability assigned by the classifiers instead of the exact class matching. Furthermore
   i haven't any "no Tag" Strings so I don't know how the Classifier behaves without them to assign the probabilities.

Is this the right approach to the problem? Is There a way To use The Stanford NER
or another JAVA API with CRF or other suitable Machine Learning Algoritm to do it?

## Update

I managed to train the CRF classifier first with each word classified independently with the tag and each group of words separated by two commas( classified as "no Tag"(0) ), then with the group of words as a single word with underscores replacing spaces but I have very disappointing results in the little test I made. I haven't quite get which features I have to include and which exclude from the ones described in the NERFeatureFactory javadoc considering they can't have anything to do with language.

## Update 2

The test results are beginning to make sense, I've divided each string(tagging every Token) from the others with two new Lines, instead of the horrible "two commas labeled with 0", and I've used the Stanford *PTBTokenizer* instead of the one that I made. Moreover I've tuned  the features, turning on the *usePrev* and *useNext* features and using suffix/prefix *Ngrams* up to 6 characters of length and other things.

The training file named training.tsv has this format:

```
rt05201201010to identifier


1442955884000 identifier


rt100005154602cv identifier


Alfred street
Street street


Robert street
Street street
```

and theese are the flags in the the propeties file:

```
# these are the features we'd like to train with
# some are discussed below, the rest can be
# understood by looking at NERFeatureFactory
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
# word character ngrams will be included up to length 6 as prefixes
# and suffixes only 
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useTags=false
useWordPairs=false
useDisjunctive=true
useSequences=false
usePrevSequences=true
useNextSequences=true
# the next flag can have these values: IO, IOB1, IOB2, IOE1, IOE2, SBIEO
entitySubclassification=IO
printClassifier=HighWeight
cacheNGrams=true
# the last 4 properties deal with word shape features
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
```

However I found another problem, I managed to train only 39 labels with 100 strings each, though I have like 150 labels with more than 1000 string each, but even so it takes like 5 minutes to train and if I rise these numbers a bit it throws a *Java Heap Out of Memory Error*.

Is there a way to scale up to those numbers with a single classifier? Is it better to train 150 (or less, maybe one with two or three labels) little classifiers and combine them later? Do I need to train with 1000+ strings each label or can I stop to 100(maybe choosing them quite different from one another)?

Comment: You have to determine probability of occurence for each of the tags provided, based on the number of observed samples? This is not machine learning problem. Is it required to clasify list of strings as a tag ? It is not clear to me as you say that you are not interested in tag given by the clasifier.

Comment: @John i wrote that because i need to have multiple choices for a single string due the overlapping between classes, for example "Library" could be a SERVICE or a PLACE, and if I use only one classifier for all the tags it gives me only one answer, so I have to look at the probabilities instead.

Comment: @John To Answer your questions: it is required to classify list of strings as a Tag but the final classification is made by the user due to this overlapping. I'm not looking at the probability of occurrence, i have to look at the structure of the labeled stings.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should be aware of is that (linear chain) CRF taggers are not designed for this purpose. They came as a very nice solution for context-based prediction, i.e. when you have words before and after named entities, and you look for clues in a limited window (e.g. 2 words before / after current word). This is why you had to insert double lines: to delimit sentences. They also provide coherence between tags affected to words, which is indeed a good thing in your case.

A CRF tagger should work, but with an extra cost in learning step which you could be avoided by using simpler (maximum entropy, SVM) but still accurate machine learning methods. In Java, for your task, wouldn't Weka be a better solution? I would also consider BIO tagging as not relevant in your case.

Whatever software / coding you use, it is not surprising that ngrams at character level gives good improvements, but I believe you may add dedicated features. For instance, since morphological clues are important (presence of an "@", upper case or digits characters), you may use codes (see ref [1]) that are a very convenient method to describe strings. You'll also most probably obtain better results by using lists of names (lexicon) that may be triggered as additional features.

[1] Ranking algorithms for named-entity extraction: Boosting and the voted perceptron (Michael Collins, 2002)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I understand that CRF is not designed for this but i choose this method because my problem has a similar background of the one described in the Karma Article linked in my question. I choose Stanford NER because it seems to me the most simple and easy to use library with CRF, i think that Weka doesn't have it. It seems difficult to me to use list of names and being language independent(at least for the western languages). Do you have any suggestion for the feature selection if i choose the SVM classifier instead? how do I choose weights in this case?

Comment: As for SVM, I'm not sure "feature selection" or "choosing weights" is crucial: either machine learning handles this, or you'll spend time fine-tuning your learning procedure (fun but not always efficient). Did you try to implement some dedicated clues detection (e.g. how phone numbers, addresses, urls are usually written, number of words in expression), if necessary using regexp or partial lexicons (first names, address parts, etc.), and provide them as additional features to SVM/CRF? Feature engineering often needs to describe more precisely what criterion may be used to distinguish classes..